# Laravel : send pivot tables data in view

Tags: php, laravel-5, pivot-table

I'm new to Laravel 5 and I have some difficulties with pivot tables, controllers and repositories.

I have the tables 'users', 'sites', 'site_user', and here is what I have now :

---

### App\Models\User

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function sites() 
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Site')
        ->withPivot('site_id', 'user_id', 'relation');
    }
}
```

---

### App\Models\Site

```
class Site extends Model {

    protected $table = 'sites';

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')
        ->withPivot('site_id', 'user_id', 'relation');
    }
}
```

---

### App\Repositories\SiteRepository

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Site, App\Models\User;

class SiteRepository extends BaseRepository
{
/**
 * The User instance.
 *
 * @var App\Models\User
 */ 
protected $user;

/**
 * Create a new SiteRepository instance.
 *
 * @param  App\Models\Site $site
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct (Site $sites, User $user)
{
    $this->model = $sites;
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get sites collection paginate.
 *
 * @param  int  $n
 * @return Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public function index($n)
{
    return $this->model
    ->latest()
    ->paginate($n);
}
```

---

### App\Http\Controllers\SiteController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\SiteRepository;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Http\Requests\SiteCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\SiteUpdateRequest;
use App\Models\Site;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller {

/**
 * The SiteRepository instance.
 *
 * @var App\Repositories\SiteRepository
 */
protected $site_gestion;

/**
 * The UserRepository instance.
 *
 * @var App\Repositories\UserRepository
 */
protected $user_gestion;

/**
 * Create a new SiteController instance.
 *
 * @param  App\Repositories\SiteRepository $site_gestion
 * @param  App\Repositories\UserRepository $user_gestion
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct (SiteRepository $site_gestion, UserRepository $user_gestion)
{
    $this->site_gestion = $site_gestion;
    $this->user_gestion = $user_gestion;

    $this->middleware('admin');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(SiteRepository $site_gestion)
{
    //$counts = $this->site_gestion->counts();
    $sites = $site_gestion->index(25);
    $links = $sites->render();
    return view('back.sites.index', compact('sites'));
}
```

---

### views\back\sites\table.blade.php

```
@foreach ($sites as $site)
    [...some code...]
@endforeach
```

---

**What I want to do is to get all the sites of the logged in user**. I've tried many things, but none of them are working. And I'm still not sure where to put the code, repository or controller...

I've read tutorials about pivot in Laravel, and I've tried with some things like this in the repo, but it doesn't work...

```
$user = $this->user->find(auth()->user()->id); //This line is working

foreach ($user->sites as $site) {
    return $site
    ->latest()
    ->paginate($n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all sites of a logged user simply do it like this:

```
$sites = Auth::user()->sites;
```

That's all you need to do to get to these sites. If you want to use query and pagination try like this:

```
$sites = Auth::user()->sites()->latest()->paginate($n);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly with 


`$sites = auth()->user()->sites()->latest()->paginate($n);`
`return $sites;`

And how could I add a condition like `->where($sites->pivot->relation, '=', 'marchand')` ?

Comment: One way is to use `(...)->sites()->join('pivot', 'pivot_id', '=', 'pivot_id')->where('relation', 'marchand')`

Comment: Now I have a new object to get : The 'sites' have many 'fontaines' (it's a relation hasMany) I would do the same thing in FontaineRepository, like : `$fontaines = auth()->user()->sites()->fontaines()->latest()->paginate($n);`
But I have the error :
_Method fontaines does not exist._
I don't know what I need to add to get that...

Comment: Up... Can you help me on this one ?

Comment: when you call `fontaines()` after `sites()` <- you have there  query builder based on `Site` model, so you have to have `fontaines()` method in `Site` model.

Comment: I have a method fontaines() in Site model, like this : `public function fontaines() 
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Fontaine');
 }`

Answer (score 0):

So what you've done seems pretty close.

So you pretty much have it, when iterating over the sites they should be instances of the site model.

```
$user = auth()->user(); // This is a way of saying your first line without a db query for the user

foreach ($user->sites as $site) {
    // each site in here is a site model
    $site->pivot->relation;
}
```

The only other thing that looks slightly strange is how you've defined the pivots. Generally when calling `withPivot` you wouldn't define the joining ids, if you wish to vary from the defaults you can pass it as an argument to the `belongsToMany` like so.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'site_user', 'user_id', 'site_id')
    ->withPivot('relation');
```